# Onecolumn vs. Twocolumn: spuriously different header spacing

Tags: spacing, sectioning, two-column, sections-paragraphs

In the following example, there's a spurious space in the one-column variant. The problem seems to be that in two-column mode, the `\section` command is at the "beginning of a column" and no space is inserted before, while in the one-column variant, there's a content before the `\section` which makes the standard before-section skip to be inserted.

How to remove the space in the one-column case?

(Remark: `multicol` is not an option.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\long\def\Xonecolumn#1{%
\vbox{\parindent0pt\relax#1\vspace{1ex}}%
}

\long\def\Xtwocolumn#1{\twocolumn[%
\vbox{\parindent0pt\relax#1\vspace{1ex}}%
]}

\let\Xcolumn\Xonecolumn
%\let\Xcolumn\Xtwocolumn

\begin{document}

\Xcolumn{{\Large In the real case, here is a title, authors, an abstract and so on and so forth\par}
\rule[1ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}

\section{My first section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: May be something like `\vspace{-2em}`  before of `\section`?

Comment: @Fran "something" like that, I can do myself. I want a general solution that doesn't need anything more inserted.

Comment: the general solution could be something as \makeatletter         
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}{1}{0mm}{0\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
{\bfseries\large}} 
\makeatother but I do not know of to make only for the first section.

Comment: @Fran Yeah, I can use `fancyhdr` anyways, the question is: How to detect if the text really starts with a sectioning command? I would be more happy to be able to "`\unskip` a future skip".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since there's no better answer, I'll answer this with my final solution:

It is an article header so in the real usage, a command `\section` will always follow. Hence we can suppress the initial space introduced by this command. In my case, this is `2.25ex plus 1.25ex minus .2ex`.

So it seems that the proper solution is

```
\long\def\Xonecolumn#1{%
\vbox{\parindent0pt\relax#1\vspace{1ex}}%
\vspace*{-2.25ex plus -1.25ex minus -.2ex}%
}
```